# Spreadsheet like functions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with the parameters for an option pricing model in rows so:

df.Spot is column with Spot prices

df.Strike is column with the Strike prices,

etc.

I have a function `blsimpv(spot, strike, rf, dy, T, price, w)` that calculate the implied volatility of an option with given parameters.  All the parameters are in the present in the dataframe. The `blsimpv` function only accepts single inputs for values.

Want to do something to create new column in the pandas dataframe by passing the values to the function.

```
df['vol']= df.applymap(blsimpv( df.spot, df.strike,  df.rf, df.dy, df.T,
                            df.MTMPrice, df.w))
```

does not work as it passes `pd.series` to my function that can only calculate on floats.
Must be a simple way of just applying function to elements in a row in pandas?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to slightly change your function (or use a wrapper function, as below) so that it accepts each DataFrame `row` as an argument:

```
def blsimpv_(row):
    blsimpv(row['spot'], row['strike'], row['rf'], row['dy'], row['T'], row['price'], row['w'])
```

Then you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) this (row-wise):

```
apply(blsimpv_, axis=1)
```